# How do I fix this Synthax Error in Python?

Tags: python

**Hi all,
I am trying to figure out where is went wrong.
The question is:**

Write a program whose inputs are three integers, and whose output is the smallest of the three values.

Ex: If the input is:

7
15
3
the output is:

3

**So I wrote this:**

```
num_1 = int(input()
num_2 = int(input()
num_3 = int(input()

def smallest (num_1, num_2, num_3)

    return min (num_1, num_2, num_3)

if num_1 < num_2 and num_1 < num_3

    smallest_num = num_1

elif num_2 < num_1 and num_2 < num_3

    smallest_num = num_2

else:

    smallest_num = num_3

print(smallest_num)
```

**However, I am getting this syntax error:**

Syntax errors detected :

Line 2:
num_2 = int(input()
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**What I am doing wrong and how can I fix this?**
**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Your missing an ending ')'

Comment: Lines 3 and 4 also have the same error... so you will need to add the `)` to all three lines.

Answer (score 1):

numbers in one line separated by space character

```
max(map(int, input().split()))
```

each number in separate line

```
N = 3
max(map(int, (input() for _ in range(N))))
```

Answer (score 0):

close the `brackets` properly and put `:` at the end of `def fun(...):`

```
num_1 = int(input())
num_2 = int(input())
num_3 = int(input())

def smallest (num_1, num_2, num_3):

    return min (num_1, num_2, num_3)

if num_1 < num_2 and num_1 < num_3:

    smallest_num = num_1

elif num_2 < num_1 and num_2 < num_3:

    smallest_num = num_2

else:

    smallest_num = num_3

print(smallest_num)
```

## better approach:

```
num_1 = int(input())
num_2 = int(input())
num_3 = int(input())
    
def largest_num(*args):
    return max(args)

print(largest_num(num_1, num_2, num_3))
```

## Output:

```
55
26
66
66
```

## One line approach:

```
count = 3
print(max(int(input()) for _ in range(count)))
```